# How do i print one ticket per element in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, printing

```
import os, sys
import win32print
import win32api


mylist = ["a","b","c","d"]

#file to print
tik = "C:\\Gestión Caja\\ tik.txt"



for i in range(len(mylist)):
    #reset the file
    Epa = open(tik,"w")
    j = mylist[i]
    #write the file
    Epa.write(f"{mylist[i]}\n")
    win32api.ShellExecute(0,"print",tik,None,".",0)
    #close the file
    Epa.close()
```

Hi , i was trying to make a ticket printing system. The code creates an .txt file where it writes the first element of the list, then its supoused to print a ticket with that element in and do the same with the rest by overwriting the same .txt file  .The idea is ,for each element of the list, print a ticket with that element in it. It prints the right amount of tickets but all with the last element of the list.

I tried by closing the file out of the loop, deleting the close() line

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to ensure that each print job waits for the previous one to finish before overwriting the file with the next element. You can achieve this by introducing a delay after the print job to allow it to finish before moving on to the next iteration.

```
import os
import win32api
import time

mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
tik = "C:\\Gestión Caja\\tik.txt"

for item in mylist:
    # Write to the file
    with open(tik, "w") as file:
        file.write(item)

    # Print the ticket
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", tik, None, ".", 0)
    
    # Add a delay to allow the print job to finish before moving to the next iteration
    time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the delay as needed
```

This code will write each element of the list to the file, print the ticket, wait for a specified amount of time (in this case, 5 seconds), and then move on to the next iteration. Adjust the delay time as needed depending on how long it takes for your printer to finish printing each ticket.